# Trying to run an SWT based GUI on Raspberry Pi

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, swt, raspberry-pi

I have developed an SWT GUI on Eclipse on Windows and now I am trying to move it to Raspberry Pi. I am searching for the SWT library for Raspberry.

I have Raspbian on in RPi. Does that mean that I need the SWT library for ARMHF? If yes, how can I import it to my program and can I compile and export the jar on the shell instead of Eclipe (because RPi has 512 MB which is not enough to run Eclipse efficiently)?

Thanks

Comment: You need the correct SWT for ARM / Linux on the RPI, this won't run on your PC so you use the Windows SWT there.

Comment: No idea about your first question, but [this](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#howbuildjar) should help with your second question.

Answer (score 0):

This may be an old post but some people will have the same problem.

You need to install these two packages: **libswt-gtk-4-java** and **libswt-cairo-gtk-4-jni**. Just run this command:

```
sudo apt -y install libswt-gtk-4-java libswt-cairo-gtk-4-jni
```

The required jar file will be found at "/usr/lib/java/swt-gtk-4.x.x.jar"
Unfortunately some features like fullscreen will not work on a very basic lightDM & xorg installation.

In case you are wondering why you can't start your application from putty and are getting the following error:

**Exception in thread "main" org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles [gtk_init_check() failed]**

you would need to set the DISPLAY variable probably by running this command first:

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0
```

which will tell the GTK implementation to connect to the local X server.